# How to prevent select2 from taking user input as one of the tag suggestions

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Implemented Select2 in my project. Using the tag feature provided in the plugin. The feature works as suggested in the documentation, however I am stuck at one point.

I have initialized the tag as follows:

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
       <label for="languages">Languages <span class="mandatory">*</span> :</label>
       <input type="text" required="" placeholder="Languages" name="languages" id="languages" class="form-control">
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#languages').select2({
     tags: languagenames,
});
```

lanugagenames data:

```
[{"id":"1","text":"Afrikaans"},{"id":"2","text":"Albanian"},{"id":"3","text":"Arabic",....}]
```

On entering characters in the input box, I get suggestions in the drop-down, however I am also getting **the entered characters as one of the suggestions** (screen attached). For example, while trying to enter english, I enter "En" and it is present as one of the suggestions. I checked the data set and there is not entry for "En". I cannot find any particular configuration to stop this extra entry. Any suggestion on how I can prevent this extra entry from appearing?

[image]

Comment: `<input autocomplete="off" />` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didnt know this plugin before, but it looks great.

Try something like this:

```
$('#languages').select2({
     tags: languagenames,
     createSearchChoice : function(term){
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

i know it a late answer .

by following the documentation you can have tag mode with `tags: true` option
so set it to false.
[see this](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags)

```
$(".js-example-tokenizer").select2({
  tags: true,
  tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']
})
```

Comment: I am still able to input text on multiselect selectbox.... is there a way to completely disable text input?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#languages').select2({
     tags: false
});
```

This worked for me on multiple select, I'm using select 4.0.9.